# Find numbers greater or lesser from the specified value

Tags: comparison, relational

I am noob not know much about languages, just want to know from a set of numbers, find greater or lesser than the specified number

an example, a txt file contains list of numbers as

1. 34598357
2. 24534666
3. 22423424

i want to find out each digit is greater or lesser.

take example as 5, i want the output as from the above 34598357 as

> 3<5,
>        4<5,
>       5=5,
>       9>5,
>       8>5,
>       3<5,
>       5=5,
>       7>5

can be done with excel? or any program to do with? any addon does this in browser?

Comment: You need somewhere to start. Almost any programming language can accomplish this, so pick one, and let us know so we can assist you further.

Comment: thnx for comment, can be done with excel?

Comment: [Here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html) seems like a good start for excel.

Comment: checked the link, but i didnt get the exact information what i need. it show only import of txt file to excel.

Comment: any help frankerz?